# Is it possible to call a variable by concatenating two strings in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to concatenate two strings and call the resulting string as a variable?

For example, suppose I have a variable `foo = "bar"` and for some very weird reason I wanted to call it with the strings `"fo"` and `"o"` such as this incomplete example:

```
foo = "bar"
weapon = "fo" + "o"
print(weapon)
```

In this case, Python will obviously output `"foo"`. How do I instead get this to output `"bar"` by using the variable `weapon`?

**I have already solved the problem a by creating a dictionary and using the resulting string as the key, but I am still curious if it is possible to call a variable using a concatenated string.**

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: Use `eval`. But you shouldn't do that. Note also, a terminology point, `foo` isn't *calling* a variable. To *call* something means to call it like a function, so `foo()` would be calling

Comment: It's possible but generally not a good idea.

Comment: `globals()[weapon]` is `globals()["foo"]` which is the value of the name "foo".

Comment: @AndrewJaffe of course, that won't work outside of the global scope